# How to convert a binary file into a Long integer?

Tags: python, algorithm, long-integer

In python, long integers have an unlimited range. Is there a simple way to convert a binary file (e.g., a photo) into a single long integer?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the usecase? Also it would help greatly if you specified Python version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module it's just:

```
bitstring.BitString(filename='your_file').uint
```

If you prefer you can get a signed integer using the `int` property.

Internally this is using `struct.unpack` to convert chunks of bytes, which is more efficient than doing it per byte.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it.

```
def file_to_number(f):
    number = 0
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            number = ord(char) | (number << 8)
    return number
```

You might get a `MemoryError` eventually.

Comment: As it's a binary file I'm not sure it makes sense to iterate over lines (I'm not sure it's harmful either, but a line just isn't meaningful in this case).

Comment: Sure; it's just the simplest way to semi-lazily read data out of a file. If there was a `for chunk in f.read_chunks(4096):` or so, I would've used that.